# decoupling jquery, sizzle?

Tags: jquery, sizzle

Does anyone have experience / insight re: decoupling jquery / sizzle?

this is for general interest, but here's the scenario that triggered my question:

..i already have jquery in the project. wanted to try out http://ecsstender.org/, which requires the Sizzle selector engine. 
I dont really want to include a 2nd copy of Sizzle - its already part of jquery ..

- would rather do something like this: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/further-decoupling-sizzle-and-jquery
- e.g. create a jquery build that depends on an external, rather than embedded, version of Sizzle - so the same Sizzle lib can be used by jquery, eccstender, or other scripts.

Seems a good idea. Although I guess it could hurt performace, and I would want to see benchmarking comparisons against the jQuery production release..

Does anyone know if this has been done ? (github fork?) Or is there a good reason against this approach? 
.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There's no need for Sizzle to be included in the jQuery build. It can be removed...the jQuery code [all references `Sizzle.`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/sizzle-jquery.js), you can just grab/compile jQuery yourself (including Sizzle beforehand) and have it exposed to any other library (not actually including it in the compiled version, just as an extern to the closure compiler).

---

*Here's the option to leave it embedded, but expose Sizzle for outside use:*

If you know jQuery will be used (dependency), just add this after jQuery:

```
​window.Sizzle = jQuery.find;
```

This will re-expose Sizzle as a property you can use.

---

*Here's the manual version to remove Sizzle from being embedded:*

In jQuery ([version 1.4.3 link](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.js)) you'll see this :

```
/*!
 * Sizzle CSS Selector Engine - v1.0
 *  Copyright 2009, The Dojo Foundation
 *  Released under the MIT, BSD, and GPL Licenses.
 *  More information: http://sizzlejs.com/
 */
(function(){
//...
//lots of code!
//...

// EXPOSE
jQuery.find = Sizzle;
jQuery.expr = Sizzle.selectors;
jQuery.expr[":"] = jQuery.expr.filters;
jQuery.unique = Sizzle.uniqueSort;
jQuery.text = Sizzle.getText;
jQuery.isXMLDoc = Sizzle.isXML;
jQuery.contains = Sizzle.contains;

})();
```

Replace that section with *only*:

```
(function(){    
// EXPOSE
jQuery.find = Sizzle;
jQuery.expr = Sizzle.selectors;
jQuery.expr[":"] = jQuery.expr.filters;
jQuery.unique = Sizzle.uniqueSort;
jQuery.text = Sizzle.getText;
jQuery.isXMLDoc = Sizzle.isXML;
jQuery.contains = Sizzle.contains;    
})();
```

Then all you need to do in include [Sizzle](http://github.com/jeresig/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js) *before* jQuery and it'll work fine.

[Here's a fiddle showing it working](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/d8vhj/7/), including Sizzle directly from github, *not* embedded in jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the eCSStender CSS3 Selectors Module with the Sizzle bundled in jQuery, you can do that:

```
eCSStender.addMethod('findBySelector',function(selector){
  var els = [];
  jQuery(selector).each(function(){
    els.push(this);
  });
  return els;
});
```

There may be an easier way to directly get an actual element collection (rather than a fake one using an array), but it's early yet and my brain isn't working quite yet.